# can't display major grid lines in empty ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to create an empty plot with just axis, title, and grid breaks. I have come so far with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 100), ylim=c(0,100)) +
  xlab("x axis") + ylab("y axis") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,by=10), minor_breaks = seq(0, 100, by=5)) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="white", size=1),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="white", size=0.5))
```

It displays the minor grid lines, but for some reason the major lines can't display.
Any clue on why and how I can see them?
Thanks,
[image]

Comment: if breaks on the axis are allowed you could consider plotting a graph and putting the line color to "transparant"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the scale doesn't have any limits (which are normally computed from data) and major breaks can't be computed. The coords has limits, but the scale doesn't know about the coord limits. Might have to set the `axis.ticks` and `axis.text` theme elements to `element_blank()` too if you want it to be closer to your plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 100), ylim=c(0,100)) +
  xlab("x axis") + ylab("y axis") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,by=10), minor_breaks = seq(0, 100, by=5),
                     limits = c(0, 100)) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="white", size=1),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="white", size=0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>